# I need to launch an external website in Onsen Ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I need to launch to launch an **external url** / website in **Onsen Ui** without leaving the app. I can use an iframe I guess between the ons-page tags where I need it but not very reliable perhaps.

Its my first Onsen Ui project.

Jimmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using the method below on OnsenUI

```
<a href="www.example.com">Link</a>
```

will destroy and replace the whole app (web view) with external HTML resources.

---

Solution: so you may need the helps of [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen) plugin.

In your case,
**launch an external url / website in Onsen Ui without leaving the app**,
you need "_self" or "_blank" ("_blank" is used for example codes below)

```
// opts is optional depend on your requirements
var opts = 'location=yes';
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', opts);
```

or you can use ngCordova's [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser)

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ctrl', ['$cordovaInAppBrowser', function($cordovaInAppBrowser) {
         var opts = {location: 'yes'};
         $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', opts);
     }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem and i use this method its not fancy but it workes for me

```
<a class="name" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OOWhuC_9Lw', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
      Watch
</a>
```